# Encrypt data on angular decrypt on Nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, encryption

What's the way of doing this? I tried using CryptoJS on angular and Crypto Module on node, without success I keep getting description error

Angular encrypt method :

```
 _rsaEnc(p) {
    var e = new JSEncrypt();
    const key = 'MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDlOJu6TyygqxfWT7eLtGDwajtNFOb9I5XRb6khyfD1Yt3YiCgQWMNW649887VGJiGr/L5i2osbl8C9+WJTeucF+S76xFxdU6jE0NQ+Z+zEdhUTooNRaY5nZiu5PgDB0ED/kaskaskKAS';
    e.setPublicKey(key);

    return e.encrypt(p);
  }
```

Node decrypt method

```
privK = {
          key: fs.readFileSync('./app/services/private.pem').toString(),
          passphrase: 'xxxxxx'
      };
      var buf = Buffer.from(base64Data, 'base64');

      origData = crypto.privateDecrypt(privK, buf);
     return origData.toString('utf-8');
```

error:

> Error: error:040A1079:rsa
>   routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:oaep decoding error

Comment: Please add error message.

Comment: ok edited the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node-rsa errors when trying to decrypt message with private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837617/node-rsa-errors-when-trying-to-decrypt-message-with-private-key)

Comment: Have you tried
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33848086/3358570?

Comment: ye i ended up changing the angular lib to jsencrypt, and the node to node-rsa to set the scheme to pkcs1

Answer (score 1):

Ended up changing the angular lib to jsencrypt, CryptoJS doesnt support RSA, and changed node lib to node-rsa to set the encryption scheme to pkcs1 with

```
myDecrypter.setOptions({encryptionScheme: 'pkcs1'});
```